# Using float positions on the x axis of an R plot with integer scaled x axis

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot with a discrete x axis from 0.0 to 1.0 in 0.1 steps that I use to represent the continuous range from 0 to 1.
And I have data in ay, by, cy and so on and x positions for these in ax, bx, cx, that have finer granularity and different values than the x axis currently has.
All vectors have the same length.

Here an example showing the ay values on the wrong x positions.

```
x <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
ax <- c(0.08, 0.13, 0.172, 0.2224, 0.357, 0.42, 0.551, 0.76, 0.79, 0.81, 0.92)
ay <- c(113.4, 111, 162.2, 35, 5, 4, 64, 74, 91, 93, 91)
plot(x, ay, type="b")
```

[image]

Is it possible **without ggplot2** to realign the x positions of the y values according to ax, bx, cx? (ax != bx != cx)

Comment: If you want the x-axis to show ax, bx, or whatever-x, why not just use `plot(ax, ay)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `plot(ax, ay)`, and then use `axis()` to specify the ticks from 0.0 to 1.0?

```
plot(ax, ay, type="b")
axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

[image]

Then plot `bx` and `by` together, `cx` and `cy`, etc.